# npm install ssh2-sftp-client is not working

Tags: node.js, npm

I am usgin MERN stack project and going to read file from SFTP server, I have to use this package

```
npm install ssh2-sftp-client
```

But gets error

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/ssh2-sftp-client/node_modules/ssh2/lib/agent.js 13:4-19

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'E:\Work\Fuse-React-v7.2.0\Fuse-React-v7.2.0-skeleton\node_modules\ssh2-sftp-client\node_modules\ssh2\lib'

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'E:\Work\Fuse-React-v7.2.0\Fuse-React-v7.2.0-skeleton\node_modules\ssh2-sftp-client\node_modules\ssh2\lib'

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'E:\Work\Fuse-React-v7.2.0\Fuse-React-v7.2.0-skeleton\node_modules\ssh2-sftp-client\node_modules\ssh2\lib'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'E:\Work\Fuse-React-v7.2.0\Fuse-React-v7.2.0-skeleton\node_modules\ssh2-sftp-client\node_modules\ssh2\lib\protocol'
Did you mean './zlib'?
```

I have tried yarn add crypto, yarn add fs, yarn add path but still gets error

Comment: What's your node/npm versions? Do you have `type: module` in your package.json?

Comment: 14.18.0 for node version and no type: module

Answer (score 1):

This question has been here for a while, but, if others face the same problem, updating the npm version solved the issue for me.

To update npm version:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```